# Is there a way in Eclipse to change the ECMAScript compliance level?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

In Eclipse 4.5 (Mars) with installed [JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), the default compliance level for ECMAScript is set to `ECMAScript 3`, which is already very outdated. And the related drop down list to change the compliance level is deactivated, so it's not possible to change the option. Is there a way to change those settings to a newer standard like `ECMAScript 5` or `ECMAScript 2015`?

[image: JavaScript validator preferences not allowing to change ECMAScript compliance level]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to use a newer compliance level directly in JSDT, but with a plugin called [`tern-java`](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-ECMAScript-support) you can use `ES5` or `ES2015` (named before `ES6`).

I added this plugin via the installation of angular-eclipse. You can find this plugin on Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: Does it support ES5/6 syntax as well? The examples on that linked page are only about new global objects.

Comment: I have no real problems with ES5. But I can't said about ES6. I never use new syntax like JS class or import/export.

Comment: Does it support ES5 => Yes. For ES6 last version of ternjs starts supporting ES6 class syntax. tern.java will integrate soon last version of ternjs but I think it will have problem with syntax coloration (it will work only for completion, hyperlink) You can play with ternjs with the demo http://ternjs.net/doc/demo.html

Comment: @Jabberwock: Using keywords like `catch` or `default` regularly trips the syntax checker for me.

Comment: @Bergi JSDT doesn't support ES6, so you will have this error. You could disable the JavaScript validation and try to use JSHint with tern.java https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter-JSHint

Comment: @Angelo: Keywords as properties is ES5 :-) I'm not using ES6 yet.

Comment: @Bergi, I have added ES6 section https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-ECMAScript6-support Please tell me if you need some other informations. Thanks

Comment: I tried Tern with ES6 and JSHint (and without) and although errors from eclipse es 3 don't display, I have errors for words such as "const" (huh?) and var (huhuh?), although I'm guessing it has more to do with the brackets. (E.g. const { BxTagButton } = require('./lib/BxTagButton');)

Comment: This plugin does not understand arrow functions.

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) added support for ECMAScript 2015 syntax and removed the *ECMAScript compliance level* option from the *Preferences* dialog.

Comment: And still it gives a warning on using the 'let' keyword -- "'let' is available in ES6". Any proper way to change that in Neon, making the checks compliant to the actual runtime used?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any warning. I assume there is a setting within the validator (under *JavaScript* > *Validator* > *Errors/Warnings*). I didn't find such a setting yet, though.

Comment: Well, I know the answer -- the warning comes from JSHint, not from Eclipse JS validator. The problem is, I still cannot switch it off, neither with a project-specific .jshintrc nor with a global configuration. The only way that seems to work, is adding /* jshint esversion: 6 */ to each and every file, which does scale for a 10 files project, but not for a x00 files one. Eclipse seems to screw up the JSHint integration in some way, so let's wait for a fix...

Comment: I see. So, this sounds like it's worth a separate question, because this one is related to JSDT (which works as expected since the Neon release.