# Eclipse IDE alternative with ECMAScript 6 validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, ecmascript-6

I'm running Eclipse Mars 4.5 with JSDT and it's getting increasingly difficult to use this for JavaScript/Node.JS development, since it doen't recognize modern patterns:

[image]

This is because the JavaScript Validator is set to ECMAScript 3.

[image]

To my surprise for such an up-to-date release of Eclipse, this dropdown is greyed out and I cannot select 5 or 5.1, let alone 6. ES3 is from 1999 (!).

Am I correct to assume that Eclipse has no considerable JavaScript community? Other FOSS projects with modern ECMAScript support:

- NetBeans supports ES5.1, ES6 in 8.1
- Atom.io supports ES6

(I haven't used these so I don't know how they compare to Eclipse)

Is Eclipse discouraged for JavaScript development? Or is there actually a well-documented non-hacky go-to plugin for Eclipse to play nice with ES6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way in Eclipse to change the ECMAScript compliance level?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624174/is-there-a-way-in-eclipse-to-change-the-ecmascript-compliance-level)

Comment: (Spoiler alert from the duplicate: surprisingly the specified eclipse plugin does not support this, but there are other options)

Comment: @Chris I invite you to mention these other options.

Comment: Refer to the duplicate - it mentioned other plugins

Comment: @Chris The one answer and its comments is all about the same plugin called 'tern'. If this can at the same time be not supporting ES6 _and_ other options, it requires some clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse Neon will improve a lot support for JavaScript with JST 2.0.0 like :

- support for ES6
- Grunt, Gulp, npm support

You can try too [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Getting-Started) if you wish advanced completion, validation where you can use for eslint, jshint which support ES6. See [Tern Linter](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter) section for that.

Comment: Note that Eclipse Neon milestones (already stable enough for usage IMO), are available at https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2016/may/article4.php . Also, the ECMAScript 6 support is introduced in this post: https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2016/may/article2.php