# Eclipse showing javascript fomatting errors, which aren't

Tags: javascript, eclipse, code-formatting

I have simple javascript code using dojo (a javascript library, but that's not important):

```
/* globals console */
define([
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/_base/declare"
], function(
    array,
    declare
) {

    var MY_MAGIC_STRING = "STRING";

    return declare("foo.bar", [], {

        constructor: function() {
            this.doSomething(MY_MAGIC_STRING);
        },

        doSomething: function(stringArg) {
            console.log(stringArg);
        }

    });
});
```

Eclipse thinks this is fine and shows no formatting errors.

However, I do not have to explicitly say that the object keys are functions, so the functions can be written as:

```
constructor() {
    this.doSomething(MY_MAGIC_STRING);
},

doSomething(stringArg) {
    console.log(stringArg);
}
```

Yet when I do this Eclipse complains, seemingly seeing an object being returned but not properly formatted, but it is.

Some of the errors produced with this simple change:

```
Syntax error on token "{", function expected
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Arguments
Syntax error on token "}", invalid MethodHeaderName
```

Is there any way to turn off formatting to this level?

I've tried:

- turning off the javascript validator builder, no change.
- Adding the folder path in the project properties > JavaScript >
  Include Path > Source, no change.
- Setting all Javascript validation Errors/Warnings to ignore, no
  change.

Comment: That's strange, method syntax in object initializers isn't exactly new, it was introduced in ES2015. What version of Eclipse is this? Are you using the built-in JavaScript linter, or some add-on? Does it have a language level setting (e.g., ES3, ES5, ES2015/"ES6", ...) somewhere?

Comment: Maybe it's not recognizing the new method syntax?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Eclipse Mars 4.5.0 - Just the built in linter, no add-ons - I've just noticed actually that in the validation there is a setting for ECMAScript Compliance which is set at ECMAScript 3, and greyed out - I'll bet that's it. So I added Tern add-on (https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-ECMAScript-support)   which is supposed to give ES5/6 support, converted the project to a Tern project, but still the errors persist

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: So you'll want to figure out why that compliance setting is disabled. At this point, I believe is this question a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624174/is-there-a-way-in-eclipse-to-change-the-ecmascript-compliance-level). Upgrading Eclipse seems the simplest solution. The current version is 4.7.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed on both, thanks for the nudge in that direction